# How can I import my API function to another Typescript file?

Tags: typescript, types, next.js

I have a function working, that gets the data from my API, but when I try to import that function in other file it does not work, it is problably something to do with TypeScript types, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

This is the function that gets API information:

```js
import { InferGetStaticPropsType } from "next";

type Post = {
  project: string;
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3100/");
  const posts: Post[] = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
};

function Blog({ posts }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Hi</h3>
      {console.log(posts)}
    </>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

I'm trying to call the above code, `Blog`, in my root index.tsx file:

```js
import type { NextPage } from "next";

import Blog from "./blog";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Blog />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is the error: [image]

If anyone wants to see the entire code [here it is](https://github.com/MestreALMO/NextJS-Testing-Express-API), the API is in the `express-api` folder.

Comment: I don't know next.js but that error is because `function Blog({ posts }` means that `Blog` requires a `posts` prop. And `<Blog />` does not have a `posts` prop.

Comment: how would you create this prop? I tryed to do it, but I can't figure this out, I think I'm not creating the prop as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getStaticProps` will only work for pages. Therefore, if your `Blog` component is not a page then it will not be called.

You could, however, move the data fetching to your `Home` page instead and then pass it along to the `Blog` component:

```js
import { NextPage, InferGetStaticPropsType } from "next";
import Blog from "./blog";

type Post = {
  project: string;
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3100/");
  const posts: Post[] = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
};

const Home: NextPage = ({ posts }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Blog posts={posts} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```js
function Blog({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Hi</h3>
      {console.log(posts)}
    </>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```